# XML with PHP SOAP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am totally new in SOAP.
and i'm currently building a system where i need to use SOAP.

here's the code

```
<?php
      require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
      header('Content-type: text/html');

      $client = new nusoap_client('http://localhost/soap/server.php');
      $err = $client->getError();

      if ($err) {

       echo '
      Constructor error


      ' . $err . '
      ';
      }

      $input = $_GET['input'];
      $data = explode(";",$input);

      $serviceName    = $data[0];
      $sourceMsisdn   = $data[1];
      $pin            = $data[2];
      $destMsisdn     = $data[3];
      $bucketType     = $data[4];
      $amount         = $data[5];
      $terminalID     = $data[6];
      $sourceRefID    = $data[7];

      $param = 
          array( 'topUp' => array(
            'serviceName'     => $serviceName, 
            'sourceMsisdn'    => $sourceMsisdn, 
            'pin'             => $pin, 
            'destMsisdn'      => $destMsisdn, 
            'bucketType'      => $bucketType,
            'amount'          => $amount,
            'terminalID'      => $terminalID,
            'sourceRefID'     => $sourceRefID    
        )
       );

      $response = $client->call('topUp',$param);


      //var_dump($response);


      if($client->fault) {

       echo "FAULT: Code: (".$client->faultcode.") ";
       echo "String: ".$client->faultstring;

      } else {

      // echo $response['name']."\n Age: ".$response['age']."'s";

      }

      $myFile = (string)$data[1] .'send.xml';
      //$param =  new \SoapVar("<topUp></topUp>");
      $response = $client->request;
      file_put_contents($myFile,$response);

?>
```

the code above produces this XML

```
POST /soap/server.php HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost
User-Agent: NuSOAP/0.9.5 (1.123)
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 882

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns4475:topUpRequest xmlns:ns4475="http://tempuri.org">
    <serviceName xsi:type="xsd:string">01</serviceName>
    <sourceMsisdn xsi:type="xsd:string">0892929292</sourceMsisdn>
    <pin xsi:type="xsd:string">12323</pin>
    <destMsisdn xsi:type="xsd:string">08289320830</destMsisdn>
    <bucketType xsi:type="xsd:string">reg</bucketType>
    <amount xsi:type="xsd:string">20000</amount>
    <terminalID xsi:type="xsd:string">AN-32</terminalID>
    <sourceRefID xsi:type="xsd:string">AN-32</sourceRefID>
    </ns4475:topUpRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

the problem is.
i want to produce a XML File like this.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns4475:topUpRequest xmlns:ns4475="http://tempuri.org">
    <item>
      <name xsi:type="xsd:string">serviceName</name>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">01</value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name xsi:type="xsd:string">sourceMsisdn</name>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">0892929292</value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name xsi:type="xsd:string">pin</name>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">12323</value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name xsi:type="xsd:string">destMsisdn</name>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">08289320830</value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name xsi:type="xsd:string">amount</name>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">20000</value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name xsi:type="xsd:string">amount</name>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">20000</value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name xsi:type="xsd:string">terminalID</name>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">AN-32</value>
    </item>
    <item>
      <name xsi:type="xsd:string">sourceRefID</name>
      <value xsi:type="xsd:string">AN-32</value>
    </item>
    </ns4475:topUpRequest>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

any kind of help will be appreciated and looking forward to it.

Thanks in advance.